# How to get javascript variable value from one page to another without get or post

Tags: javascript, session, variables

I have a jquery ui menu with a button that opens a ligthbox styled iframe once the button is clicked. I want the button click event to grab the selected menu value and send it to the page that gets opened in the iframe. I've tried a few things that just don't work. The guy at the link below devised a solution that makes javascript session variables without cookies, but I couldn't pass a variable to Session.setVar(string name, mixed value), it always returned false meaning the session wasn't set. It only worked when I passed a string as the value.
http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/javascript-session-variables-without-cookies/

myCode:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $(".menu").menu({
          var selection =  ' ';
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('.selected', this).removeClass('selected');

          // selection is that variable I want to pass to the page that opens in the iframe:

          selection = ui.item.addClass('selected').children('a').attr('name');

           } // closes select function
    }); // closes menu

    $("button").click(function(){

       //when the button is clicked the css lightbox effect happens and the div below opens an iframe containing the other page. 

               $("#light").css("display", "block");
               $("#fade").css("display", "block");

            }); //closes click()
}); // close function()
</script>

//iframe:

<div id="light" class="white_content"><iframe height= "400px" width ="450px" src="http://mydomain.com/invite_1.php"></iframe> </div>

<div>
        <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                <li><a href="#" name="academic_artStudies" id="academic_artStudies"><img src="" alt="" /><h2>Academic: Art Studies</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="academic_Literature"><img src="" alt="" /><h2>Academic: Literature</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="academic_socialSciences"><img src="" alt="" /><h2>Academic: Social Sciences</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="academic_physicalNaturalSci"><img src="" alt="" /><h2>Academic: Physical/Natural Sciences</h2></a></li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need cookies or local storage for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URL Parameters, if that is convenient.

Comment: That would be a GET request ?

Comment: Ah right. An alternative I can think of is, write a value setter Javascript/jQuery method in the iFrame page and call it from the parent document. The setter method should set the value of global var.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that Vishwanath, but will do some research and try to figure that out. Thanks.